# attaching word template by reference

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, styles

I have a custom template that I've attached to a collection of documents.  I have these files, including the template, checked into source control.  I'm finding that the reference to the attached template does not follow the files when a second user checks out the documents and template from source control.

I.e. my coworker checks out the template and one of the documents.  He edits the template to change Header 1 to color red. He opens the document and the Header 1 text is not red.  The auto-update based on template is turned on.  It is in fact referencing the original template that is stored in my folder on the network.

Can I create the documents so that they look in their own path for the template?